# on click listener on convert view to make image view visible

Tags: android, listview, view, imageview, onclicklistener

My List view contains a `TextView` and a `ImageView` that at first image view is `INVISIBLE` and by clicking each item it will be `VISIBLE` here is my adapter:

```
public class ContentViewrAdaptor extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<String> originalData = null;
private List<String> filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Typeface regular;
private Context context;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


public ContentViewrAdaptor(Context context, List<String> data, Typeface regular) {
    this.filteredData = data;
    this.originalData = data;
    this.regular = regular;
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAccept);

        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        holder.text.setTypeface(regular);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.image.setTag(position);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, (Integer) holder.image.getTag() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            ImageView iv = vh.image;
            if (iv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    if (filteredData.get(position).contains("font"))
        holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(filteredData.get(position)));
    else
        holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));
    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
}


public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}


private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                filterableString = filterableString.replaceAll(filterString, "<font color='red'>" + filterString + "</font>");
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

foe example when i click on first item the forth item will be visible too , this problem will cause when list is scroll

what is the problem ? how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your Adapter is reusing the Views as you scroll, but you're only settings the View's status when onClicked() is called.

If you want to avoid that, one solution would be having a secondary List containing the visibility state of the View.

e.g.

```
ArrayList<Integer> visiblePositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAccept);

        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        holder.text.setTypeface(regular);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.image.setTag(position);
    adjustImageVisibility(viewHolder, visiblePositions.contains(position));

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onViewClicked(holder, position);
        }
    });

    if (filteredData.get(position).contains("font")) holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(filteredData.get(position)));            
    else holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

public void onViewClicked(ViewHolder viewHolder, Integer position){
    if (visiblePositions.contains(position)) {
         adjustImageVisibility(viewHolder.image, false);
         visibilePositions.remove(position);
    } 
    else {
         adjustImageVisibility(viewHolder.image, true);
         visiblePositions.add(position);
    }
}

public void adjustImageVisibility(ImageView imageView, boolean visible){
    if(visible) imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

That should work for you by backing the position of a clicked item and having the Adapter's getView() method use that position when building the View to display.

Note: if for some reason the order of your list changes, this solution will likely fail.

A better one would be to create an Object that holds both the String to display and a boolean value for its visibility, then let the Object handle it by itself.

But this should point you in the right direction for that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a separate array to hold the states of the images for each group. Here's my interpretation of this.

```
private boolean[] mImageStates;

public ContentViewrAdaptor(Context context, List<String> data, Typeface regular) {
    ...
    mImageStates = new boolean[getCount()];
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAccept);

        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        holder.text.setTypeface(regular);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, (Integer) holder.image.getTag() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ImageView imageView = holder.image;
                int position = Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag().toString());
                if (mImageStates[position]) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mImageStates[position] = false;
                } else {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mImageStates[position] = true;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.image.setTag(position);

    if (mImageStates[position]) {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (filteredData.get(position).contains("font")) {
        holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(filteredData.get(position)));
    } else {
        holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));
    }

    return convertView;
}
```